# EO.WebBrowser set referer C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webbrowser-control, awesomium

Trying to find a way to set the referer in EO.WebBrowser.
I saw that the User-Agent can be changed with:`webView1.CustomUserAgent` but looks like there is no method for the referer. Are there any other ways to get this working in javascript or by other means?

I can "capture" the beforesendheaders event, with this: `webView1.BeforeSendHeaders += new EO.WebBrowser.RequestEventHandler(webView1_BeforeSendHeaders);`, but doesn't help that much.

I'm working on a project, and I started with awesomium, but... looks like some websites are not loaded, it's just showing a blank screen. I've managed to change both referer and user agent in awesomium, but I really need both to move on.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found it myself, using javascript.
Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string JS_referer_function = "function navigateToUrl(url) {var f = document.createElement(\"FORM\"); f.action = url; var indexQM = url.indexOf(\"?\"); if (indexQM>=0) { var params = url.substring(indexQM+1).split(\"&\"); for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) { var keyValuePair = params[i].split(\"=\"); var input = document.createElement(\"INPUT\"); input.type=\"hidden\"; input.name  = keyValuePair[0]; input.value = keyValuePair[1]; f.appendChild(input); } } document.body.appendChild(f); f.submit(); }";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webView1.LoadUrlAndWait("http://referer.com");
        webView1.EvalScript(JS_referer_function);
        webView1.EvalScript("navigateToUrl(\"http://192.168.0.108/referer\");");
    }
}
```

It's basically loading http://referer.com first, and using javascript, goes to http://192.168.0.108/referer using the referer http://referer.com.